# Vagrant NFS share doesn't show updated file if size doesn't change on PhpStorm

Tags: nfs, caching, vagrant

I searched in many place but I don't find an answer to my question.
Same question has already posted here : https://serverfault.com/questions/534507/vagrant-nfs-share-doesnt-show-updated-file-if-size-doesnt-change

But the solution is only for Sublime Text. I use Jetbrain **PhpStorm 8**.

The problem is exactly the same, my NFS doesn't detect my file change if the file size doesn't change too.

Already two weeks with this problem, it will make me crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late, but I had the same problem and I found out that underlying winnfsd.exe library that vagrant uses is bugged (as you can see here: https://bitbucket.org/jankowfsky/winnfsd/issues/7/winnfsd-doesnt-always-overwrite-files).

There is an updated library which has the bug resolved here: https://bitbucket.org/yannschepens/winnfsd-new/downloads

You need to download updated library and replace existing library, which is located on your disk in the installation directory of vagrant-winnfsd plugin - for me it is

```
C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\gems\gems\vagrant-winnfsd-1.0.11\bin\winnfsd.exe
```

So, just take downloaded winnfsd.exe and replace existing one. Fire up vagrant and problem should be solved.

Comment: Wow nice thanks you for your solution, it's very nice for other people who have the same problem! For me, finally I got WmWare with Vagrant plugin and the sync speed is VERY nice! :)

Answer (score 0):

As per this part of the Laracast forum: 
https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=1757-slow-responses-on-homestead/p1#p7700

> "Make sure you edit /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and set "sendfile" to off if
>   using NFS or you will run into weird caching issues."

I too use PHPStorm8 - did the fix, and vagrant reload. (note doing a simple nginx restart didn't help the problem but a vagrant reload did)

Comment: Yes, but my SendFile (EnableSendfile on Apache) option is already on Off on my config :(